# Data Versioning/Auditing in SQL Database best patterns

Tags: sql-server

I have a Job table where I post the Job description, posted date, qualifications etc.. with below schema

```
Job(Id @@Identity PK, Description varchar (200), PostedOn DateTime, Skills Varchar(50))
```

Other attributes of jobs we would like to track such as Department, team etc will be stored in another table as Attriibutes of Job

```
JobAttributesList(Id @@Identity PK, AttributeName varchar(50))
JobAttributes(JobID @@Identity PK, AttributeID FK REFERENCES JobAttributesList.Id, AttributeValue varchar(50))
```

Now if a job description has changed, we do not want to lose old one and hence keep track of versioning.What are the best practices? we may have to scale later by adding more versioning tables
A strategy would be to use a History table for all the tables we want to enable versioning but that would add more and more tables as we add versioning requirements and I feel its schema duplication.

Comment: You could possibly use triggers to achieve that at the DB level. Otherwise at the data access layer. Just a couple of hints...

Comment: So..you are saying, use duplicate schema tables for history and update them using triggers? can u please elaborate?

Comment: Hum, I was thinking about the update mechanism. Duplicate schema for a couple of tables is viable. However, for everything, it quickly becomes unbearable. I recall using a generic mechanism where the change was kept in text form in a log table that kept track of who did what and when. You can relatively easily code that using triggers.

Comment: A sophisticated solution would be to keep the full log at the database level and use a tool to audit that log. That would be DB specific though.

Comment: In the previous proposed solution, you could have datetime, table name, user ID, log text (log text could be Jason for easy parsing)

Comment: but the proposed approach do not work to retrieve the previous data though isn't it. It just shows who did what and when?

Comment: The changed data is kept in the text field in JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between versioning and auditing. Versioning only requires that you keep the old versions of the data somewhere. *Auditing* typically requires that you also know *who* made a change.

If you want to keep the old versions in the database, *do* create an "old versions" table for each table you want to version, but *don't* create a new table for every different column change you want to audit.

I mean, you can create a new table for every column, whose only columns are `audit_id, key, old_column_value, created_datetime`, and it can save disk space if the original table is very wide, but it makes reconstructing the complete row for a given date and time extraordinarily expensive.

You could also keep the old data in the same table, and always do inserts, but over time that becomes a performance problem as your OLTP table gets way, way too big.

Just have a single table with all the columns of the original table, which you always insert into, which you can do inside an `update, delete` trigger on the original table. You can tell which columns have changed either by adding a bit flag for every column, or just determine that at select time by comparing data in one row with data in the previously audited row for the given key.

I would absolutely not recommend creating a trigger which concatenates all of the values cast to varchar and dumps it all into a single, universal audit table with an "audited_data" column. It will be slow to write, and impossible to usefully read.

If you want to use this for *actual auditing*, and not just versioning, then either the user making the change must be captured in the original table so it is available to the trigger, or you need people to be connecting with specific logins, in which case you can use transport information like `original_login()`, or you need to set a value like `context_info` or `session_context` on the client side.